# Fully customizable GUI for R?

Tags: r, user-interface, standards

My research team has a series of "relatively" standard analyses that they run for different experiments, but need slightly different analysis procedures. I want to give them the freedom to analyze their own data, despite being programming naive. I would like to create a GUI that asks them a series of questions that will lead them to the right script (which I will have written, and have available on the back end) so that they can just push "run" and have their analysis spit out.

Any ideas on how to create a GUI that will lead them to the right script would be fantastic. Even better would be a GUI that allows them to input variable names, which then amend the code so that the outputs are a little more custom.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a web server (intranet or internet), [Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) can do what you want. It is a web application layer on top of R.